# Trying to toggle 2 divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've found lots of answers for toggling divs, but none are quite doing what I'm looking for. I want to have 2 buttons (grid & list views). When the page loads, the grid div is visible. If someone clicks the list view button, the grid div will go to display: none, and the list div will display:block. If you happen to click the list view button again while the list div is already displayed, nothing would happen. But if you click on the grid view button, the divs would toggle again, and vice versa.

All I've managed to accomplish is that clicking on the "list view" button displays that div, but it does not make the grid view disappear. Only clicking on the grid view button makes the grid disappear. I'm sure there's a logic I'm completely missing here, and I apologize for having a fried brain right now. But I'm just getting frustrated.

Here's my code:

```js
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
          var objdiv = $('#div'+$(this).attr('target'));
          var toggleDisplay = false;
          if(objdiv.css('display')=="none"){
                toggleDisplay = true;
          }
          jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
          jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).toggle(toggleDisplay);
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
  <a class="btn btn-primary showSingle" target="1" data-bs-toggle="button" aria-pressed="true"><i class="fas fa-th-large"></i></a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary showSingle" target="2" data-bs-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false"><i class="fas fa-list"></i></a>
</div>

<div id="div1" style="display: block;">
    Grid View Here
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display: none;">
     List view here
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DRY (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) point: If the content is the same for the "Grid View" & for the "List View", you might prefer doing just one div witth the content and apply the selectionned style (grid or list)

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. Unfortunately, I don't actually have the expertise to hack the isotope script to do just that. I need to go from a grid of filtered & sorted info, to a list that's also filtered and sorted. At least at the moment, repeating the data, in a different format, is going to the be path of least resistance. Once the whole thing gets approved (or not), I can pursue doing it a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic you're using is more complex than it needs to be. All you need to do when a button is clicked is hide all the `#divN` elements, which can be done most simply by adding a common class to them, then showing the one related to the button which was clicked.

To target the `div` related to the button you can put the `id` selector in the `href` attribute of the `a` element. Try this example:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.showSingle').click(e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.content').hide();
    let targetSelector = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
    $(targetSelector).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.content { display: none; }
#div1 { display: block; }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-block">
  <a class="btn btn-primary showSingle" href="#div1" data-bs-toggle="button" aria-pressed="true"><i class="fas fa-th-large"></i></a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary showSingle" href="#div2" data-bs-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false"><i class="fas fa-list"></i></a>
</div>

<div class="content" id="div1">Grid View Here</div>
<div class="content" id="div2">List view here</div>
```

Comment: This was *exactly* what I needed! Thank you SO very very much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help